# Syntax Errors Everywhere

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error

I have been trying to make a simple trivia game and my console keeps saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Line: 6"                              I would greatly apreciate any assistance!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript Other Stuff</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        var question1=prompt("What Does HTML stand for? (lowercase) ")
        var question2=prompt("How Many Letters Are In the Alphabet?")
        var quesiton3=prompt("How Mant Fingers Do You Have? (number form)")
        
        if question1 = ("hyper-text markup language") {
            
            alert("Correct!")
        }
        else alert("Incorrect... the correct answer was hyper-text markup language!")
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in `if` condition, you must check the variable for the correct string in the condition, it will be correct:

```js
        var question1=prompt("What Does HTML stand for? (lowercase) ")
        var question2=prompt("How Many Letters Are In the Alphabet?")
        var quesiton3=prompt("How Mant Fingers Do You Have? (number form)")
        
        if (question1 === "hyper-text markup language") {
            
            alert("Correct!")
        }
        else alert("Incorrect... the correct answer was hyper-text markup language!")
```

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much!!